# How to normalize data when all attributes are dependent on a primary key?

Tags: ms-access

I want to normalize the following set of data:

```
Catalogue No.,
Title,
Platform,
No. of Disks,
Synopsis,
Reviews,
Genre,
Rating,
Release Date,
Screen Shots,
Characters,
Developer,
Member Rating
```

Would I split this data up or just keep it as one big table? It will be a catalog section to my database holding various information as shown.

Comment: The answer to this question seems almost wholly dependent upon how you will be reading and writing the data, how many records you expect to be working with, the performance requirements, the hardware, etc. -- in short, upon information which you should consider providing as part of your question.

Comment: Move anything that ends with an "s" to a new table.

Comment: Why do you suggest that? :)

Comment: An im sorry im trying to get my head around normalization and its not setting in too quickly what so ever "/